# What is the syntax for passing 2d arrays through functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I want to write a function that finds the sum of the values of a column in a 2D array.

The function prototype is:
int columnSum(int array[][NUM_COLS], int numRows, int target)

Where NUM_COLS and numRows are the number of columns and rows in the array, respectively, and target is the index of the column to be summed. I have written some things below, but my compiler doesn't accept it. Any tips/solutions on how to code this would be much appreciated (please try to use as simple language as possible).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int columnSum(int [][NUM_COLS], int, int);

int main() {
    int rows = 3, cols = 3;
    int test[rows][cols] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
    int sum = columnSum(test, rows, 0);
    cout << "Sum of the columns: " << sumCol << endl;
}

int columnSum(int array[][NUM_COLS], int numRows, int target) {
    int sumCol = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
          sumCol = sumCol + a[i][target]; 
    return sumCol;
}
```

Comment: What's `NUM_COLS`? It doesn't appear to be declared anywhere. Anyway, the function expects an array with `NUM_COLS` columns, but `test` doesn't look like one.

Comment: Where is definition of NUM_COLS ?

Comment: `target` is another undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `columnSum` a **function template** and use **nontype template parameters** as shown below. Here we take the array by reference as the first parameter of the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
//N and M are non-type template parameters
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
int columnSum(int (&array)[N][M], int target) {
    assert(target >= 0 && target < M);  //make sure we don't go out of bounds
    int sumCol = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
          sumCol = sumCol + array[i][target]; 
    return sumCol;
}

int main() {
    
    int test[3][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
    int sum0 = columnSum(test, 0);
    std::cout << "Sum of the column 0 is: " << sum0 << std::endl;
    
    int sum1 = columnSum(test, 2);
    std::cout << "Sum of the column 1 is: " << sum1 << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/mcnok9HTg).

---

Also, note that in Standard C++ the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. So take for example,

```
int rows = 3, cols = 3;
int test[rows][cols]; //this is not standard c++ since rows and cols are not constant expressions
```

The statement `int test[rows][cols];` is not standard c++ since both `rows` and `cols` are not **constant expressions**.